# How to grab and drag an element around a circle?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

So far I have a circle with a marker.

http://jsfiddle.net/x5APH/1/

I would like to grab and drag the marker around the circle, however the current functionality only nudges the marker when you click it.

What changes can I make to the code so that the marker can be dragged around the circle while the mouse is held down?

**Note**

If you could update the fiddle with your solution I would greatly appreciate it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

changed some code

```
        $(document).ready(function(){               

            $('#marker').on('mousedown', function(){
                $('body').on('mousemove', function(event){
                    rotateAnnotationCropper($('#innerCircle').parent(), event.pageX,event.pageY, $('#marker'));    
                });

            });                    
        }); ​
```

also add this code

```
$('body').on('mouseup', function(event){ $('body').unbind('mousemove')});
```

in the function

this is the jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/sandeeprajoria/x5APH/11/

Comment: Thanks Sandeep, This was exactly what I was looking for.  I replaced the `$('body')` selector with `$(document)` just so the movement can continue if someone goes outside the browser window

Comment: There's one problem with my code http://jsfiddle.net/x5APH/16/, I noticed that you need to click directly on the middle of the block to move it.  Is there a way I can click on a corner of it to move it fluidly?

Comment: well I tried clicking on the corner of the box...it seems to work fine...what exactly are you looking for....

Comment: Hmm, I don't know why, but sometimes when I click it and then move the cursor immediately after, the cursor gets stuck.  I noticed this occur in firefox more than in chrome or ie

Answer (score 0):

To do anything of this sort:

On `mousedown` on the desired element, set:

- `mousemove` event on the document to update the position of the target
- `mouseup` event on the document to remove the `mousemove` and `mouseup` events you just set.

Example in plain JS:

```
elem.onmousedown = function() {
    document.body.onmousemove = function(e) {
        e = e || window.event;
        // do stuff with e
    };
    document.body.onmouseup = function() {
        document.body.onmousemove = document.body.onmouseup = null;
    };
};
```

Personally I like to improve this further by creating a "mask" element over the whole page to capture events, so that (for example) dragging a selection or image does not trigger default browser actions (which are strangely immune to all event cancelling methods in this case...)

Comment: Thanks Kolink for the `mousemove` and `mouseup` concept.  Would you be able to update the fiddle if you have the time?

Comment: Unfortunately not, because I adamantly refuse to use jQuery (for a number of very good reasons). The concept isn't too hard, especially since you already have the code to do the movement. Just remove the current `onclick`, and replace it with the structure I gave in the answer.

Comment: @Kolink, I would like to hear some of these reason why you refuse to use jQuery, I am personally a user of it but I have never heard of a reason not to use it, and would appreciate hearing some.

Comment: @Dale Such a conversation would be off-topic here. However you are more than welcome to contact me at the email address on my profile page to discuss this matter.